# Missing Ruby Version on ASDF

Tags: ruby, asdf

I am trying to install Ruby 2.7.7 via asdf but the latest version appears to be 2.7.6. Anyone happen to know how to support a new Ruby version on asdf?

[Available Ruby 2.7.x versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbfHe.png)

Tried installing Ruby 2.7.7, expected version to be available.

Comment: Per the plugin docs: *"Under the hood, asdf-ruby uses ruby-build to build and install Ruby, check its README for more information about build options and the troubleshooting wiki section for any issues encountered during installation of ruby versions."*. Have you tried upgrading `ruby-build` as shown [Here](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/blob/master/README.md)?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The `asdf-ruby` plugin uses [ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build) to actually build Ruby versions. To be able to install new Ruby versions, ruby-build needs to be updated.

You can set the desired ruby-build version by setting the `ASDF_RUBY_BUILD_VERSION` environment variable to the desired version before invoking `asdf`.

Alternatively, you can also update your asdf-ruby plugin to use the current ruby-build version on every invocation as they have updated the plugin to use the current ruby-build version by default in [asdf-vm/asdf-ruby#317](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby/pull/317).

This can be done with either

```
asdf plugin update --all
```

or

```
asdf plugin update ruby
```

to just update the ruby plugin.

Comment: Updating ruby-build worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `asdf plugin update --all` / `asdf plugin update ruby` doesn't work for you it means the ruby version is missing from ruby-build.

You can probably either comment on the issue or open an issue on:

https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues